# Generalization of multiplication and addition of vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I am writing a paper about neural networks and have showed that, if a layer takes as input a vector and produces a vector, how a layer performs the vector-to-vector function as the affine function $f(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{W}\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{b}$ where $\mathbf{W}$ is a matrix and $\mathbf{b}$ is a vector. But such a function is also computed when the input $\mathbf{x}$ is a tensor of arbitrary dimension($\mathbf{W}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ are then tensors of corresponding dimensionality).

So the matrix multiplication becomes a multiplication of tensors. The behavior of this should be similar to the `dot` function in numpy. And well, the addition should just be addition for tensors.

How would you mathmatically talk about such function? Is it called anything special for tensors? I have looked at the tensor product but I have a hard time figuring out if that is it - it does not seem as if there is a concrete explanation of this and how to apply it but rather a very abstract definition.

So for example, for a 2-dimensional tensor(so a matrix) input $\mathbf{x}$, $\mathbf{W}$ would be a 3-dimensional tensor and $\mathbf{b}$
$$
\mathbf{W} = [[[1,2], [4, 5]], [[2,2], [4, 10]]]\\
\mathbf{x} = [[1,2], [3,4]]\\
\mathbf{b} = [[[1,1], [1, 1]], [[2,2], [2, 2]]]
$$
$\mathbf{W}$ has shape (2,2,2), $\mathbf{x}$ has shape (2,2), and $\mathbf{b}$ has shape (2,2,2).

The result of this operation is the result of `np.dot(W,x) + b` which is:
$$
[ [[ 8 11]
  [20 29]],
 [[10 14]
  [36 50]] ]
$$
of shape (2,2,2).

Thanks!

Comment: The only kind of "product" between tensors of arbitrary dimension is the tensor product. From what you describe, it sounds like you're looking for some kind of [contraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_contraction) of the tensor product $W \otimes x$.

Comment: If you could explain what your operation is for an example where $x$ is a tensor of order at least $2$, then perhaps we could tell you more concretely how one might describe the operation mathematically

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thank you, sir! Let me devise an an example :)

Comment: @BenGrossmann Okay, I now have an example :)

Comment: The numpy documentation gives a nice description: "If a is an N-D array and b is an M-D array (where M>=2), it is a sum product over the last axis of a and the second-to-last axis of b." That said, "axis" isn't standard mathematical terminology but with some tweaking this is descriptive enough

Comment: @BenGrossmann Indeed. But so doesn't the behavior replicate a tensor product? Or some other standardized operation? Was that the contraction you were talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $\mathbf x$ is an order $n$ tensor and $\mathbf W$ is an order $m$ tensor. Suppose that $\mathbf W$ has entries $w[i_1,\dots,i_{m}]$ where $1 \leq i_k \leq p_k$ for $1 \leq k \leq m$ and $\mathbf x$ has entries $x[j_1,\dots,j_n]$ where $1 \leq j_k \leq q_k$ for $1 \leq k \leq n$. Moreover, we are given that $q_n = p_{m-1}.$

The "product" $\mathbf {Wx}$ is the order $m + n - 2$ tensor $\mathbf y$ whose entries are given by
$$
y[i_1,\dots,i_{m-2},i_m,j_1,\dots,j_{n-1}] = \sum_{k=1}^{q_n} w[i_1,\dots,i_{m-2},k,i_{m}]x[j_1,\dots,j_{n-1},k].
$$
For comparison, the tensor product $\mathbf W \otimes \mathbf x$ is the $m+n$ tensor $\tilde{\mathbf y}$ whose entries are given by
$$
\tilde y[i_1,\dots,i_{m-2},i_{m-1},i_m,j_1,\dots,j_{n-1},j_n] = 
w[i_1,\dots,i_{m-2},i_{m-1},i_{m}]x[j_1,\dots,j_{n-1},j_n].
$$
The tensor $\mathbf y$ can be described as the contraction of $\tilde{\mathbf y}$ over its $(m-1)$th and $(m+n)$th indices.

Comment: Gosh. Thank you so very much <3